# Solving "Gaps and Islands" with row_number() and dense_rank()?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, rank

How does one solve the islands part of [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) with [`dense_rank()` and `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html). I've seen this now a few times and I'm wondering if someone could explain it,

Let's use something like this for example data (example uses PostgreSQL),

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT x AS id, trunc(random()*3+1) AS x
  FROM generate_series(1,50)
    AS t(x);
```

Which should produce something like this.

```
 id | x 
----+---
  1 | 3
  2 | 1
  3 | 3
  4 | 3
  5 | 3
  6 | 2
  7 | 3
  8 | 2
  9 | 1
 10 | 3
...
```

What we want is something like this...  *(where `z` is some value that we can use to `GROUP BY`)*

```
 id | x | grp
----+------
  1 | 3 | z
  2 | 1 | z
  3 | 3 | z
  4 | 3 | z
  5 | 3 | z
  6 | 2 | z
  7 | 3 | z
  8 | 2 | z
  9 | 1 | z
 10 | 3 | z
...
```

Such that we can do either

- `GROUP BY x,grp` where `(x,grp)` is a unique island
- `GROUP BY grp` where `grp` is a unique island.

That would look like this for (x,grp) in the above example.. *(where `z` is some value that we can use to `GROUP BY`)*

```
 id | x | grp
----+------
  1 | 3 | 1
  2 | 1 | 1
  3 | 3 | 2
  4 | 3 | 2
  5 | 3 | 2
  6 | 2 | z    -- Because we're grouping by an (x,grp)
  7 | 3 | z    -- Does not have to be `3` (or something unique)
  8 | 2 | z    -- z=1, is fine to use again if we 
  9 | 1 | z    -- GROUP BY (x,grp)
 10 | 3 | z
```

## Background

This has come up only a few times in answers in my research.

- [Using Row_Number to find consecutive row count](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6633/2639) by @Martin Smith
- [Getting each status change in a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56594/2639) by @Martin Smith
- [Grouping or Window](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166625/2639) by @ErikE

It also seems to **explicitly confuse others though it has never been explained on this network**,

- [Question 1 (never explained), solved and accepted with `lag()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/157191/2639)
- [Question 2 (never explained), solved an accepted with `lag()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/131916/2639)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the trick here is a property of two equally incrementing series which produce a difference that can be used to identify islands `{11,12,13} - {1,2,3} = {10,10,10}`. This property isn't enough to identify islands in and of itself, but it's a crucial step that we can exploit to do so.

## Background

Stepping aside from the problem. Let's check this out.. Here we

- Define 1 *group* as 3 rows.
- Create one *group* for each pair/row of offsets in xoffsets.

Here is some code.

```
SELECT x1, x2, x1-x2 AS difference
FROM (VALUES
  (2,42),
  (13,7),
  (42,2)
)
  AS xoffsets(o1,o2)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT x+o1,x+o2  -- here we add the offsets above to x
  FROM generate_series(1,3) AS t(x)
) AS t(x1, x2)
ORDER BY x1, x2;

 x1 | x2 | difference 
----+----+------------
  3 | 43 |        -40
  4 | 44 |        -40
  5 | 45 |        -40
 14 |  8 |          6
 15 |  9 |          6
 16 | 10 |          6
 43 |  3 |         40
 44 |  4 |         40
 45 |  5 |         40
(9 rows)
```

This looks pretty good, and grouping by the `difference` would be good enough in this example. You can see we have three groups starting at       `(2,42)`, `(13,7)`, and `(42,2)`, corresponding to the groups in `xoffsets`.  This is essentially the problem in reverse. But we have one *major* issue because we're demonstrating this with *static* offsets. If the difference between any two offsets `o1-o2` is the same we'll have a problem. Like this,

```
SELECT x1, x2, x1-x2 AS difference
FROM (VALUES
  (100,90),
  (90,80)
) AS xoffsets(o1,o2)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT x+o1,x+o2  -- here we add the offsets above to x
  FROM generate_series(1,3) AS t(x)
) AS t(x1, x2)
ORDER BY x1, x2;

 x1  | x2 | difference 
-----+----+------------
  91 | 81 |         10
  92 | 82 |         10
  93 | 83 |         10
 101 | 91 |         10
 102 | 92 |         10
 103 | 93 |         10
```

We'll we have to find a way define the second offset statically.

```
SELECT x1, x2, x1-x2 AS difference
FROM (VALUES
  (100,0),
  (90,0)
) AS xoffsets(o1,o2)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT x+o1,x+o2  -- here we add the offsets above to x
  FROM generate_series(1,3) AS t(x)
) AS t(x1, x2)
ORDER BY x1, x2;

 x1  | x2 | difference 
-----+----+------------
  91 |  1 |         90
  92 |  2 |         90
  93 |  3 |         90
 101 |  1 |        100
 102 |  2 |        100
 103 |  3 |        100
(6 rows)
```

And, again we're back on track to making groups for each pairs of offsets. This isn't quite what we're doing, but it's pretty close and hopefully it serves to help illustrate how the two sets can be subtracted to create islands.

## Application

Now let's revisit the problem above with table `foo`. We sandwich the variables between two copies of `x` for display purposes only.

```
SELECT
  id,
  x,
  dense_rank() OVER (w1) AS lhs,
  dense_rank() OVER (w2) AS rhs,
  dense_rank() OVER (w1)
    - dense_rank() OVER (w2)
    AS diff,
  (
    x,
    dense_rank() OVER (w1)
      - dense_rank() OVER (w2)
  ) AS grp,
  x
FROM foo
WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY id),
  w2 AS (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY id)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10;


 id | x | lhs | rhs | diff |  grp  | x 
----+---+-----+-----+------+-------+---
  1 | 2 |   1 |   1 |    0 | (2,0) | 2
  2 | 1 |   2 |   1 |    1 | (1,1) | 1
  3 | 2 |   3 |   2 |    1 | (2,1) | 2
  4 | 3 |   4 |   1 |    3 | (3,3) | 3
  5 | 3 |   5 |   2 |    3 | (3,3) | 3
  6 | 2 |   6 |   3 |    3 | (2,3) | 2
  7 | 3 |   7 |   3 |    4 | (3,4) | 3
  8 | 1 |   8 |   2 |    6 | (1,6) | 1
  9 | 3 |   9 |   4 |    5 | (3,5) | 3
 10 | 1 |  10 |   3 |    7 | (1,7) | 1
(10 rows)
```

You can see here all of the variables at play, in addition to `x` and `id`

- The `lhs` is simple. We're just generating a unique sequential identifier with that (because we're feeding it a unique sequential identifier: `id` -- though never forget that [ids are seldom gapless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985219/124486))
- The `rhs` is slightly more complex. We partition by `x` and generate a sequential identifier with that amongst the different `x` values. Observe how `rhs` increments over the set each time it sees a row with a value that it has already seen. The property of `rhs` is *how many times the value was seen*.
- The `diff` is the simple result of subtraction but it's not too useful to think of it like that. Think of more like subtracting a sequence than digits (though they're digits for any single row). We have a sequence increasing by one for the amount of times a value is seen. And, we have a sequence increasing by one for every distinct id (every time). Subtracting these two sequences will return the same number for repeating values, just like in our example above. `(11,12,13) - (1,2,3) = (10,10,10)`. This is the same principle in the first section of this answer

  - `diff` doesn't independently mark the group by itself
  - `diff` forces all identical islands of `x` into a group (which may have false-positives, ex. the three cases where `diff=3` above and their corresponding `x` values)

The group `grp` is a function of `(x, diff)`. It serves as the grouping id, albeit in a slightly weird format. This serves to reduce false positives that would happen if we *just* grouped by diff.

## Simple Unoptimized Query

So now we have our simple unoptimized query

```
SELECT x, diff, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    x,
    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY id)
      - dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY id)
    AS diff
  FROM foo
) AS t
GROUP BY x, diff;
```

## Optimizations

On the matter of replacing `dense_rank()` with something else, like `row_number()`. [@ypercube commented](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35912040#35912040)

> It also works with ROW_NUMBER() but I think it may give different results with different data. Depends if there are duplicate data in the table.

So let's review it, here is a query that shows

- `row_number()` and `dense_rank()`
- the respective differences computed.
- over a result set that includes, ids, `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,6,7,8`, and two different "islands" of `x` vals.

SQL Query,

```
SELECT
  id,
  x,
  dense_rank() OVER (w1) AS dr_w1,
  dense_rank() OVER (w2) AS dr_w2,
  (
    x,
    dense_rank() OVER (w1)
    - dense_rank() OVER (w2)
  ) AS dense_diffgrp,
  row_number() OVER (w1) AS rn_w1,
  row_number() OVER (w2) AS rn_w2,
  (
    x,
    row_number() OVER (w1)
    - row_number() OVER (w2)
  ) AS rn_diffgrp,
  x
FROM (
  SELECT id,
  CASE WHEN id<4
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
  FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,8)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM generate_series(6,8)
  ) AS t(id)
) AS t(id,x)
WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY id),
  w2 AS (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY id)
ORDER BY id;
```

Result set, **`dr` dense_rank, `rn` row_number**

```
 id | x | dr_w1 | dr_w2 | dense_diffgrp | rn_w1 | rn_w2 | rn_diffgrp | x 
----+---+-------+-------+---------------+-------+-------+------------+---
  1 | 1 |     1 |     1 | (1,0)         |     1 |     1 | (1,0)      | 1
  2 | 1 |     2 |     2 | (1,0)         |     2 |     2 | (1,0)      | 1
  3 | 1 |     3 |     3 | (1,0)         |     3 |     3 | (1,0)      | 1
  4 | 0 |     4 |     1 | (0,3)         |     4 |     1 | (0,3)      | 0
  5 | 0 |     5 |     2 | (0,3)         |     5 |     2 | (0,3)      | 0
  6 | 0 |     6 |     3 | (0,3)         |     7 |     3 | (0,4)      | 0
  6 | 0 |     6 |     3 | (0,3)         |     6 |     4 | (0,2)      | 0
  7 | 0 |     7 |     4 | (0,3)         |     8 |     6 | (0,2)      | 0
  7 | 0 |     7 |     4 | (0,3)         |     9 |     5 | (0,4)      | 0
  8 | 0 |     8 |     5 | (0,3)         |    10 |     8 | (0,2)      | 0
  8 | 0 |     8 |     5 | (0,3)         |    11 |     7 | (0,4)      | 0
```

You'll see here, that when the column you're ordering by has duplicates you can't use this method because you can't *ensure* an ordering for a query that has duplicate in the `ORDER BY` clause. It's very much just the effect of the ordering of the duplicates that throws off the difference: the relationship of the global incremeneting value to the incrementing value over the partition. However, when you have an unique id column, or a series of columns that define uniqueness, by all means **use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`.**