# Count Consecutive Codes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, gaps-and-islands

I'm searching for a query (cannot figure it out myself at the moment with the help of already found queries around here. The quest I have is the following one: I have a view that gives following output

```
  ResourceID | ReferenceDate | CodeID 
 ------------|---------------|-------- 
         893 | 2018-05-14    |      1 
         656 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
         656 | 2018-05-22    |      1 
         353 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
         530 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
         541 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
         755 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
          55 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
         382 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
         224 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
        1115 | 2018-05-07    |      1 
         191 | 2018-05-07    |      5 
         191 | 2018-05-08    |      5 
         191 | 2018-05-09    |      5 
         655 | 2018-07-06    |      6 
         655 | 2018-07-10    |      6 
         892 | 2018-07-06    |      6
```

I want to group the CodeID's with a sort by ResourceID and then ReferenceDate. With this result I want to get something like the following table

```
  ResourceID | CodeID | Count 
 ------------|--------|------- 
         893 |      1 |     1 
         656 |      1 |     2 
         353 |      1 |     1 
  ...
         191 |      5 |     3 
         655 |      6 |     2 
         892 |      6 |     1
```

### This to get to a result where we can say that ResourceNumber x has y consecutive days CodeID z.

EDIT: The question looks like this one but with the difference (as far as I see it) that I need to have the count combination or ResourceID and CodeID: [Determine consecutive occurrences of values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210907/determine-consecutive-occurrences-of-values)

---

Code to create sample data for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Resources
(
    ResourceID INT NOT NULL,
    ReferenceDate DATE NOT NULL,
    CodeID INT NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Resources
    (ResourceID, ReferenceDate, CodeID)
VALUES
        ( 893, '2018-05-14',1), 
        ( 656, '2018-05-07',1), 
        ( 656, '2018-05-22',1), 
        ( 353, '2018-05-07',1), 
        ( 530, '2018-05-07',1), 
        ( 541, '2018-05-07',1), 
        ( 755, '2018-05-07',1), 
        (  55, '2018-05-07',1), 
        ( 382, '2018-05-07',1), 
        ( 224, '2018-05-07',1), 
        (1115, '2018-05-07',1), 
        ( 191, '2018-05-07',5), 
        ( 191, '2018-05-08',5), 
        ( 191, '2018-05-09',5), 
        ( 655, '2018-07-06',6), 
        ( 655, '2018-07-10',6), 
        ( 892, '2018-07-06',6);
```

Comment: Looks like trivial `SELECT ResourceID, CodeID, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY ResourceID, CodeID`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "Consecutive"? Resource 656 has a gap of 15 days between it's dates.

Comment: @Cowthulhu It's just the consecutive records sorted by date, it does not always mean that the dates will follow up nicely. Sorry for not being complete on this.

Comment: `with a sort by ResourceID and then ReferenceDate` - I'm not following your output, then. You have CodeID 1 with ResourceID 893, then 656, then 353. Those are not in order by ResourceID, and the dates corresponding to those ResourceIDs are also not used in any obvious way for sorting. Please provide better sample data that covers edge cases (like when a different code *does* interrupt the sequence and how that affects the count).

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly you need to set a group every time CodeID changes. You can try by using LAG() function.

> ```
> WITH ct1 AS
> (
>   SELECT
>       ResourceID, ReferenceDate, CodeID,
>       IIF(COALESCE(LAG(CodeID) OVER (ORDER BY ResourceID, ReferenceDate), 0) <> CodeID
>           AND 
>           COALESCE(LAG(ResourceID) OVER (ORDER BY ResourceID, ReferenceDate), 0) <> ResourceID, 
>          1, NULL) Rst
>   FROM
>       Resources
> )
> , ct2 AS
>   (
>     SELECT
>         ResourceID, ReferenceDate, CodeID,
>         SUM(Rst) OVER (ORDER BY ResourceID, ReferenceDate) as Grp
>     FROM
>         ct1
>    )
>    SELECT
>        ResourceID, CodeID, COUNT(*) CntCodeID
>    FROM
>        ct2
>    GROUP BY
>        ResourceID, CodeID, Grp;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ResourceID | CodeID | CntCodeID
> ---------: | -----: | --------:
>         55 |      1 |         1
>        191 |      5 |         3
>        224 |      1 |         1
>        353 |      1 |         1
>        382 |      1 |         1
>        530 |      1 |         1
>        541 |      1 |         1
>        655 |      6 |         2
>        656 |      1 |         2
>        755 |      1 |         1
>        892 |      6 |         1
>        893 |      1 |         1
>       1115 |      1 |         1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9d4a93de82f8112c16002dd659c8c55e)*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information though it is still just counting the number of codes as I see it with this code. I've added some test records to the db<>fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c135a6b9ea6b7fbeb8061cd5846f72af. Resource 191 has a codeID = 1 in between the Code 5 records and still it is just counting all the code 5 together instead of CodeID = 5 x 3, CodeID = 1 x 1, CodeID = 5 x 3.