# Calculate running total of "consecutive days without views" for each group, that can restart multiple times within each group based on conditions

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, sum, running-totals

**Summary**

I'm working to create a counter metric that shows, for each client's slug, the number of consecutive days of zero views.

- The counter should increase for each consecutive day that the client's slug doesn't receive a view.
- If/once the slug gets a view, then the counter should restart.

I can figure out a regular running total, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it restart. I've tried several ways with aggregate/window functions, but I can't seem to achieve the desired results.

---

**Source data** `dcev_zero_views_flag`

| client_name | slug | calendar_date | views | consecutive_zero_views_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z | 3 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 |

For reference, the `consecutive_zero_views_flag` column in returns `1` if the view count for the current and preceding day = 0. Otherwise, it returns `0` . It's derived by:

```
case when 
  dcev.views = 0 
  and dcev.views = lag(dcev.views) over (PARTITION by client_name, slug ORDER BY dcev.calendar_date) 
then 1 
else 0 
end as consecutive_zero_views_flag
```

---

**Desired output**

I want to add a column, `consecutive_days_without_views`. That should represent a running total of the `consecutive_zero_views_flag` for each (client_name slug) combination ordered by date. But, the running total should restart any time `consecutive_zero_views_flag` changes from 1 to 0 for each client_name/slug combination, in order of date.

**Example of desired output**

Note the last row of the example below that shows the 2 for `consecutive_days_without_views`.

| client_name | slug | calendar_date | views | consecutive_zero_views_flag | consecutive_days_without_views |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | canyon_properties | 2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Ambition LLC | city_station_apartment_homes | 2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | east_side_living_spaces | 2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D&D Properties Inc | happy_mountain_homes | 2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the answer. It's a fairly classic gaps & islands problem.

CTE

- Generate row id overall
- Generate id for the zero flag combination
- Generate id based on differential of first two ids

Excerpt

```
, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by client_name asc, slug asc, calendar_date asc) id_overall
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by client_name, slug, consecutive_zero_views_flag order by client_name asc, slug asc, calendar_date asc) id_zero_flag
    , ((ROW_NUMBER() over (order by client_name asc, slug asc, calendar_date asc))-(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by client_name, slug, consecutive_zero_views_flag order by client_name asc, slug asc, calendar_date asc))) id_diff_overall_zero_flag
```

Then, the query

- Add case when consecutive zero flag is 1, return row number that's partitioned by the differential ID

Excerpt

```
case 
     when consecutive_zero_views_flag=1 
        then ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id_diff_overall_zero_flag order by client_name asc, slug asc, calendar_date asc)
     else 0 
     end as consecutive_days_without_views
```

I referenced numerous sources to get to this solution. Here are a few, in no particular order, in case you have a similar challenge to solve:

- [Solving "Gaps and Islands" with row_number() and dense_rank()?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167068/solving-gaps-and-islands-with-row-number-and-dense-rank)
- https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/09/27/gaps-islands-problem-postgres/
- https://bertwagner.com/posts/gaps-and-islands/